# Prevent ehcache trying to access internet on startup

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, ehcache

I have a fairly simple non-clustered application running ehcache with spring and hibernate.

On startup I'm getting this error:

```
<06-Sep-2010 19:14:05 o'clock BST> <Error> <Net>  <Failed to communicate with proxy:   10.x.x.x/8080. Will try connection www.terracotta.org/80 now.
```

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

How do I prevent this call?

Here is my ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false" monitoring="off" dynamicConfig="false">


<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="60" timeToLiveSeconds="60"
     overflowToDisk="false" >
      <terracotta clustered="false"/>
</defaultCache>
```

I am certain that this ehcache.xml is being picked up and used e.g. no classpath issues.

I'm using: ehcache 2.0.1, and hibernate 3.3.1.GA

Comment: Annoying, isn't it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When adding `updateCheck="false"` to your `<ehcache />` element doesn't work, try setting the system property, either with `-Dnet.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck=true` at the command line or `System.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck", "true")` programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for this - it actually turned out to be quartz doing the update check see: http://blog.cherouvim.com/disabling-quartz-and-ehcache-update-checker/

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
 updateCheck="false">

...

</ehcache>
```